# JMeter Scripting: Not getting the dynamic value from response code

Tags: jmeter, httpwebresponse, dynamic-values

I am experienced in HP Loadrunner but new in Jmeter. 
I recently recorded a script in Jmeter 3.0 where one of the step is to upload a .pdf file. it is a 2 step process:

Step 1> on the upload window click Browse to locate the pdf file from local drive. Once this is done the server puts the file in a temporary directory in the backend and creates a metadata (dynamic value) for it

FYI: I placed the PDF file in the local folder: "Documents\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\"

Step 2> Once the local file path has been specified (above step) and the button "Upload File" is clicked the file actually gets uploaded to the server and it gets stored permanently.

At this step I need to provide that dynamic value (metadata) to successfully submit the request.

The problem I am having is Jmeter is not returning the metadata (or dynamic value) on the Step-1 of the upload process-

[Screenshot: Request/Response details from Jmeter (Step-1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/votoC.jpg)

I recorded the same steps in Vugen 12.53 and it is returning the dynamic value fine for the Step-1-

[Screenshot: Request/Response details from Vugen (Step-1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AytEJ.jpg)

Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: I'd try to set `Implementation` to `HttpClient4` as a first step. Otherwise it defaults to `Java`, and that library has its issues. Also `referrer` could be important when workflow is involved.

Comment: I tried setting  "Implementation" to "HttpClient4"  and the "referrer" is already added to the request "Header" section. Still no luck...not getting the dynamic value in response. Can you please eloborate a little bit more about what issue you are noticing with the library? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

Simply selecting "**Implementation**" to either "**Java**" or "**HttpClient3.1**" solved the problem.

*Points to be noted:

- In the "File Path" field either you need to provide the full path of the file location in local drive ("C:/user/Documents/...PerfTest_file_1.pdf") or place the PDF file in the "bin" folder of the Jmeter application folder and just provide the file name (PerfTest_file_1.pdf) as the path
- Parameter value for "**File**" (in my case "blob") should be same as the "**Parameter Name**" for the file to be attached*

Answer (score 0):

I can see LoadRunner and JMeter configuration mismatch when it comes to file upload block, I believe you should amend `Files Upload` section configuration like:

- **File Path:** full path to your PDF file. If you placed in into JMeter's "bin" folder it may be just `PerfTest_file_1.pdf`
- **Parameter Name:** this guy is the MOST important and this is where you seem to be having clash. Looking into LoadRunner screenshot you name

  ```
  "Name=file", "Value=blob\\PerfTest_file_1.pdf", "File=Yes", ENDITEM,
  ```

  and in JMeter for some reason you set this "Name" bit to "blob". I guess correct setting would be "file":

  [image: File Upload JMeter]

Other settings seem to be fine.

Going forward in order to avoid such situations you can just record your test scenarios. You need to have files you will be uploading in JMeter's "bin" folder so it could locate it while capturing file upload requests.

References:

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for taking time and looking into the issue. I actually tried the solution you suggested and still got the same result- not getting the expected response/dynamic value in the response log

Comment: In addition, for loadrunner I placed the PDF inside "blob" folder which itself is within the script folder. And for Jmeter I placed the PDF in the "bin" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, this is how the request header looks like in JMeter-

[Screenshot: JMeter Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fehM3.jpg)